# How to draw horizontal line in ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview, listviewitem

Is there any better way to draw a black horizontal line than defining layout with fixed height and black background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ListView allows you to define a divider drawable. See the android documentation on the [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) for more information.

The Divider will be drawn after each item in your list without the need for you to do anything about it. You can use a drawable or a color as the divider and you can also specify the divider height for the whole list.

Comment: It works with drawable, but it's not shown when it is a color defined in xml. I read that it's a bug - do you know from which Android version it was fixed?

Comment: I'm developing against 1.6 (SDK Version 4) and it works with xml defined colors. I can post code if you are interested.

Comment: My target platform is 1.5 and it doesn't work, so this might suggest that they fixed it in Donut.

Answer (score 1):

[API Demos List5.java](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List5.html) demonstrates including separators, using `android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1`